# Apache CXF IncompatibleClassChangeError websphere 6

Tags: java, apache, websphere, cxf

The IBM Websphere 6.1 server start well without error 
Meanwhile when i enter the wsdl adress I'm obtainning Imcompatible Change Error exception error . Iam using apache CXF and I am compiling my project in Java JDK 1.5 (with maven 2.0.9) 
Can someone help me about this issue ?
 Thanks in advance

```
[4/26/13 18:36:44:225 CEST] 00000026 ServletWrappe E SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: CXFServlet. Exception thrown : java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.addExtensibilityElements(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:229)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingInput(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:355)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingOperation(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:324)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBinding(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:305)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:193)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:148)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.WSDLQueryHandler.writeResponse(WSDLQueryHandler.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:592)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3548)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:818)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:126)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)

[4/26/13 18:36:44:254 CEST] 00000026 WebApp E [Servlet Error]-[CXFServlet]: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.addExtensibilityElements(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:229)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingInput(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:355)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingOperation(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:324)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBinding(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:305)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:193)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:148)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.WSDLQueryHandler.writeResponse(WSDLQueryHandler.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:592)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3548)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:818)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:126)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)

[4/26/13 18:36:47:118 CEST] 00000022 ServletWrappe E SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: CXFServlet. Exception thrown : java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.addExtensibilityElements(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:229)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingInput(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:355)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingOperation(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:324)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBinding(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:305)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:193)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:148)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.WSDLQueryHandler.writeResponse(WSDLQueryHandler.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:592)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3548)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:818)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:126)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)

[4/26/13 18:36:47:123 CEST] 00000022 WebApp E [Servlet Error]-[CXFServlet]: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.addExtensibilityElements(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:229)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingInput(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:355)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingOperation(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:324)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBinding(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:305)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:193)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:148)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.WSDLQueryHandler.writeResponse(WSDLQueryHandler.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:592)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3548)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:818)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:126)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)

[4/26/13 18:36:47:790 CEST] 00000021 ServletWrappe E SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: CXFServlet. Exception thrown : java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.addExtensibilityElements(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:229)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingInput(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:355)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBindingOperation(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:324)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.buildBinding(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:305)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:193)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ServiceWSDLBuilder.build(ServiceWSDLBuilder.java:148)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.WSDLQueryHandler.writeResponse(WSDLQueryHandler.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:592)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:525)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3548)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:818)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:126)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
```

Comment: You need to compile in IBM JDK (Comes with WebSphere), for starters. This may or may not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error occurs when you request the WSDL, it is likely that it is caused by an incompatibility between the version of the WSDL4J library included in WAS 6.1 and the one expected by CXF. To avoid this, you should change the class loader policy for your application to parent last.